# Como puedo agregar mi lista de canciones MP3 almacenadas en mi SD y agregarlas a un ListView para luego reproducirlas en ANDRIOD Studio?

Tags: listview, audio, memoria, mp3

Estoy necesitando agregar una lista de canciones que estan almacenadas en mi memoria SD; quiero agregarlas a un listView y posteriormente reproducirlas en un reproductor. Ya tengo mi reproductor que si funciona; pero me falta poder agregar las canciones al listView.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo visitar este portal web te ayudara con lo que quieres:

https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764